# Vue 3 v-Bind on css transition animation don't compile correctly

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, translate

I have a project in Vue + Vite, where I'm kinda trying to slide horizontally and verically some slides. I really need the new vue 3 feature to v-bind my current offeset to some animations parameters , the goal is tracking where the page is slide and using this as parameter in 0% keyframe. I'm open to suggestions to a better workflow, but the problem is that if I pass to scss (or css already tried) the v-bind(variableName) it compiles not with the value but with some "var(--7a7a37b1-variableName)".

Vue component code (animations are @import-ed in App.vue):

```
<script>
import TestComp from './TestComp.vue';
import { store } from '../store';
export default {
  components: {
    TestComp,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      store,
      animationClass: '',

      orizontalOffset: 0 ,
      verticalOffset: 0,

      color: 'red'
      
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goRight(){ 
      this.orizontalOffset = this.orizontalOffset - 100
      console.log('this.orizontalOffset',this.orizontalOffset);
      this.animationClass = 'goRight'

    },

     goLeft() {
      this.orizontalOffset = this.orizontalOffset + 100
      console.log('this.orizontalOffset', this.orizontalOffset);
      this.animationClass = 'animationRight'

    },

    goCenter() {
      this.orizontalOffset = 0
      console.log('this.orizontalOffset', this.orizontalOffset);
      this.animationClass = 'goCenter'
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <!-- main template -->
  <main>
   <div class="mainContainer" :class="this.animationClass">
     <div class="topContainer">

        <div class="card">
            <TestComp />
          </div>

      </div>

      <div class="centerContainer ">


        <div class="card">
          <TestComp />
        </div>
        <div class="card" >
          <p>carta centrale</p>
          
          <button @click="this.left--"> back</button>
          <TestComp />
          <button @click=" goRight()"> next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
           <button @click=" goLeft(), console.log((this.left))"> back</button>
          <TestComp />
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="bottomContainer">

          <div class="card">
              <TestComp />
            </div>

        </div>
   </div>
  </main>
</template>

<style lang="css" scoped>
main {
  transform: translate(-100vw,-100vh);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
  background-color: v-bind(color);
}
p {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
}
.topContainer {
  transform: translate(100vw);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.centerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.bottomContainer {
  transform: translate(100vw);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.card {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px dashed red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

</style>

/* // here's all animations  */

.goRight {
  animation: goRight 1s ease-in-out forwards;
  
};

@keyframes goRight {

  // 0% {
  //   translate: ;
  // }

  100% {
   translate: v-bind(orizontalOffset) 0 ;
  }
};

.goCenter {
  animation: goCenterFromRight 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes goCenter {

   0% {
    translate: v-bind(orizontalOffset);
  }

    100% {
        translate: 0 0;
    }
}
```

I tried avoiding Scss, but same problem.
I tried add a more simple css bg-color to v-bind the var color, but still got style="--e9eea4ec-color: red" this weird result.
Besides I know that to correctly add the prop in translate i need to concatenate the tracking number to a "vw" string before passing to the css, but my prob is before this for now.

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: This is [Scoped CSS](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css), you can use `:global` or remove `scoped` in `style` tag.